# Does Baywatch-style CPR work?

Tags: medical-science, mortality, water

It's a common movie scene. Someone falls in a large body of water and drowns, losing consciousness. Our hero rescues the victim, gives 10 seconds of CPR, emits various imprecations to the tone of "Wake up, g**damnit!" and our victim coughs up some water and wakes up.

> CUT to Bremmer, who drives a terrified Marcy in an SUV. "We can all be together now, Rose," Bremmer tells Marcy. The car slows as it approaches a police checkpoint. Ashley and Derek roar up behind Bremmer who SLAMS on the gas. The SUV races for the lake and PLUNGES into the water. Derek dives in after the car and pulls Marcy from the passenger-side window. Just then, Bremmer opens his eyes and grabs Marcy's legs. Out of nowhere, Hotch appears and FIRES his gun underwater, killing Bremmer. Moments later, Derek administers CPR on Marcy. "Stay with me!" he yells. Suddenly, the girl GASPS and spits up a stream of water. She will live. Case closed ... or is it?
>   —["Criminal Minds" Out of the Light (2011)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1875189/synopsis)

[image]

Here is the breakdown of the claims I think are *very* debatable

- That CPR actually revives people, instead of merely keeping them alive until help arrives.
- That CPR is actually effective on someone who breathed water
- That if the patient is revived, they will simply cough up a glass of water
- That someone can actually be conscious and merely a bit stunned after being revived by CPR.

Are any of these supported by facts? If not, how would our hero save the damsel in distress in real life?

Comment: What does this have to do with Baywatch? And since your question has nothing to do with the image or the position displayed _in_ the image, why is the image there?

Comment: Also, for those interested in answer, here is a [great place to start looking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPR#Society_and_culture).

Comment: ALSO, do you qualify for the epithet 'heroine' merely by swimming fail?

Comment: @dav It's a movie cliche therefore you have to have an hero and an heroine :-)

Comment: Ugh. TV medicine. So many things wrong, so little time.

Comment: @Sklivvz:  Don't you mean *damsel in distress* rather than heroine?  She's not the rescuer, she's the rescuee.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[image]

**CPR on Television**

I don't know how many times I've seen CPR done on television where the patient immediately wakes without exhibiting any major outward signs of the effects caused by either the cause of the cardiac arrest or the CPR itself.

In the real world, this is very, very often not the case.

While there are some aspects of CPR as shown on television which are correctly portrayed, there are also some which are incorrect or at least inaccurate. Whether this is done for dramatic purposes or due to lack of knowledge on the subject is up for debate.

*For the purposes of this answer, it will be much easier if we assume that all CPR done on television is done correctly.*

**The science...**

A paper studying depictions of CPR in 3 different (Rescue 911, ER, Chicago Hope) American television programs states quite clearly:

> The survival rates in our study are
>   significantly higher than the most
>   optimistic survival rates in the
>   medical literature, and the portrayal
>   of CPR on television may lead the
>   viewing public to have an unrealistic
>   impression of CPR and its chances for
>   success. Physicians discussing the use
>   of CPR with patients and families
>   should be aware of the images of CPR
>   depicted on television and the
>   misperceptions these images may
>   foster.[source](http://www.samblackman.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2007/01/1578.pdf)

The breakdown of this study by victim is as follows:

[image]

A more recent study examined 26 episodes of Casualty, Casualty, 25 episodes of Holby City, 23 episodes of Grey's Anatomy and 14 episodes of ER screened between July 2008 and April 2009 and came to a similar conclusion.

> Whilst the immediate success rate of
>   CPR in medical television drama does
>   not significantly differ from reality
>   the lack of depiction of poorer medium
>   to long term outcomes may give a
>   falsely high expectation to the lay
>   public. Equally the lay public may
>   perceive that the incidence and likely
>   success of CPR is equal across all age
>   groups. [source](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19699021)

Already we can see that research indicates a sharp disparity between the effectiveness of CPR in reality and on film. Survey data cited by the Robert Wood Johnson Foundation further indicates that:

> The public seriously overestimates
>   CPR's effectiveness. A survey that
>   included health care workers found
>   that those who were over 65 years old
>   predicted a 59 percent survival rate
>   for a person treated with CPR. People
>   under 30 were even more optimistic,
>   predicting a 75 percent survival rate.
>   s[ource](http://www.rwjf.org/pr/product.jsp?id=21335)

This data sheds light on the fact that **the success rate of CPR may not only be misrepresented by the media but by the textbooks as well**...

> Even more troubling, the surveyors
>   found, was that those who had medical
>   training estimated CPR's effectiveness
>   at 75 percent! In an effort to
>   understand why this would be so, the
>   authors examined a standard text used
>   to train health care workers and found
>   only a brief acknowledgement that CPR
>   was unlikely to be effective. The
>   handbook that the Red Cross uses to
>   teach its CPR classes to the public
>   did not confront the issue of low CPR
>   success at all. [source](http://www.rwjf.org/pr/product.jsp?id=21335)

### ***CPR in the real world***

**Q: Does CPR alone revive people?**

**A: No. But it depends on if the person receiving it was actually in cardiac arrest to begin with. And what was wrong with him in the first place.**

As we've already seen, the effectiveness of CPR (when done correctly) varies widely, even when combined with other therapies.

> Despite the development of electrical
>   defibrillation and the more recent
>   implementation of lay rescuer
>   defibrillation programs, the vast
>   majority of these victims do not leave
>   the hospital alive. In studies over
>   the past 15 years, only 1.4% of
>   patients with out-of-hospital arrest
>   in Los Angeles, Calif, survived to
>   hospital discharge; in Chicago, Ill,
>   the number was 2%, and in Detroit,
>   Mich, it was <1%. Conversely, a few
>   municipalities such as Seattle, Wash,
>   report much higher survival rates from
>   SCA—more than 15% in 1 study—which
>   suggests that survival rates need not
>   remain so low. Recent work in Europe
>   and elsewhere has confirmed that a
>   higher survival-to-hospital discharge
>   rate is indeed a realistic goal, with
>   survival rates as high as 9% reported
>   in Amsterdam and 21% in Maribor,
>   Slovenia. [source](http://circ.ahajournals.org/cgi/content/full/117/5/704?eaf)

Given the innumerable causes which can lead to cardiac arrest, I obviously cannot address them all, however, there may be some instances when CPR alone can be lifesaving, or appear to the lay rescuer that it is lifesaving.

[Recent revisions of standards](http://scienceblog.com/community/older/2000/A/200000488.html) by the American Heart Association no longer call for lay-people to perform a pulse check prior to initiating CPR if they find an unconscious victim who appears not to be breathing.  So, the person receiving the CPR may not always be in cardiac arrest.

It's possible in these situations for the painful stimuli to rouse the unconscious (usually intoxicated) person in a manner similar to what is seen on tv.  To the lay person and to bystanders without medical training, this would look exactly like what is pictured on tv.

**Ventricular Tachycardia, Ventricular Fibrillation vs. True Asystole**

The human heart requires both electrical and mechanical activity to pump blood effectively. A patient who is pulseless and not breathing may not necessarily be "flat-lined" and in certain cases, the inititation of CPR immediately may have an effect similar to that of a [precordial thump](http://www.heartcentertraining.com/blog/precordial-thump)(which is now reccomended in certain situations), in that the force of the impact induces an electrical stimulus which jolts the heart out of a non-perfusing rhythm.

In [Ventricular Tachycardia](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/PMH0001239/), the heart's electrical activity looks like this, but the person will often not have a pulse (because although the heart has electrical activity and some mechanical activity as well, it is inadequate to pump blood properly):

[image]

In [Ventricular Fibrillation](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/PMH0004467/), the heart's activity looks like this, but the person will NOT have a pulse (again, because in this rhythm, the heart is unable to effectively pump):

[image]

In true asystole (flatline) there is neither electrical nor mechanical activity in the heart:

[image]

However, without an EKG it is impossible to tell which rhythm a person's heart is in, and there is some chance (although probably quite remote) that the initial compression of CPR might jolt a person out of the first two, but not the third.

In reality, reversing a cardiac arrest is dependent largely on fixing the underlying cause.
[CPR is mainly effective by continuing to perfuse the body's tissues](http://www.hmc.org.qa/heartviews/VOL1NO1/03BACK_BASICS.htm) (especially the brain) with oxygen (and some other things), which will lessen damage and increase the chance of survival while other treatments (which are more effective at increasing survival rates) are administered. Typically, this involves electrical, drug, or surgical treatments. Although there are many variations, here is one example of an [ACLS protocol](http://www.acls.net/aclsalg.htm) for treating a cardiac arrest in full asystole, as you can see, it often requires much more than just CPR.

[image]

An often unaddressed factor in television is the potential for injuries caused by the CPR itself:

> The most common injuries from chest
>   compressions are rib fracture (∼30
>   percent) and sternal fracture (∼20
>   percent). Other common
>   complications include aspiration,
>   gastric dilatation, anterior
>   mediastinal hemorrhage, epicardial
>   hematoma, hemopericardium, myocardial
>   contusion, pneumothorax, coronary air
>   embolus, hemothorax, lung contusion,
>   and oral and dental injuries. 
>   The liver is the most commonly
>   injured intraabdominal organ, with
>   rupture occurring in about 2 percent
>   of cases. The spleen is infrequently
>   injured and ruptures in less than 1
>   percent of resuscitation attempts.
>
> Rare injuries (incidence less than 1
>   percent) include tracheal injuries,
>   esophageal rupture, gastric rupture,
>   cervical spine fracture, vena caval
>   injury, retroperitoneal hemorrhage,
>   and myocardial laceration.
>
> Complications may occur even with
>   properly performed CPR, especially rib
>   and sternal fractures. The possibility
>   of injury should not deter the
>   vigorous application of CPR, since the
>   outcome without effective
>   resuscitation is certain death.
>   Life-threatening injuries from CPR,
>   such as laceration of the heart or
>   great vessels, are rare. Proper
>   techniques will lessen the incidence
>   of serious complications. [source](http://www.ctsnet.org/edmunds/Chapter14section3.html)

**Q:  Is CPR actually effective on someone who breathed water?**

**A:  Sometimes, but not as often as television would have you think.**

There is some debate about the effectiveness of rescue breathing in CPR, and in fact, lay rescuers are now taught a compressions-only method.

> The role of rescue breathing is
>   currently debated; however, it is
>   likely important in prolonged arrests
>   or those of non-cardiac etiology.
>   Current recommendations encourage
>   inclusion of rescue breaths by trained
>   responders, but allow for elimination
>   of rescue breathing and emphasis on
>   chest compressions for responders
>   untrained or unconfident in rescue
>   breathing.[source](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21516073)

A study done in a lifeguarded waterpark environment yields the following information:

> Analysis of 63,800,000 guests with
>   56,000 rescues and 32 LSR rescues
>   shows that children and shallow water
>   both had relatively high levels of
>   rescues [62.6% for children aged 1-12
>   years and 42% for water depth less
>   than 1.52 m (5 ft)] and LSR rescues
>   [53.2% for children aged 1-12 years
>   and 65.6% for water depth less than
>   1.52 m (5 ft.)] with 87.5% of the LSR rescues resuming spontaneous
>   respiration and 75% having a poolside
>   neurological rating of Alert. [source](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21500049)

The numbers here seem to indicate a much more impressive success rate than demonstrated above with CPR, but to understand how this works, it's important to understand the physiology of drowning.

The data appears favorable, mainly because these victims are often unconscious, but not yet in cardiac arrest.  Also, the age of the patient, time spent without oxygen, and many other factors can affect survival rates.

> When water enters the lungs the
>   victim's blood chemistry is rapidly
>   altered, often leading to heart
>   failure. In fresh water drownings
>   inhaled water is immediately absorbed
>   into the blood causing hemodilution.
>   The diluted blood quickly leads to
>   heart failure due to ventricular
>   fibrillation, a condition simply
>   described as shivering of the heart,
>   or anoxia (oxygen starvation). Sea or
>   salt water creates the opposite
>   effect. Water is drawn from the blood
>   into the lungs. This process causes
>   the blood to become more concentrated,
>   leading to an increased load on the
>   heart and heart failure. Older
>   drowning victims may experience
>   immediate heart failure as a result of
>   the initial trauma of drowning,
>   particularly in extremely cold
>   water.[source](http://www.lib.niu.edu/1982/ip820732.html)

**How does the drowning process happen?**

A very basic outline of the drowning process:

> 1. Panic and violent struggle to return to surface
> 2. Period of Calmness
> 3. Swallowing of fluid, followed by vomiting
> 4. Terminal Gasp
> 5. Unconsciousness
> 6. Possible Seizures
> 7. Death
>
> *The time that this takes is variable, but it could be as little as 12 to 20
>   seconds from the first panic to unconsciousness. [source](http://www.sutcliffe.ca/joel/nls/drowning.pdf)

A book on forensic pathology details the process a little more delicately:

[image]
[source](http://books.google.com/books?id=XyG3802xSdwC&pg=PA400&lpg=PA400&dq=physiology%20of%20drowning&source=bl&ots=cVYOavjOsl&sig=a5P3sbIWkV4valM7MVSza4UB7BU&hl=en&ei=5FzdTeSAGdSEtgfe9ojPDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=physiology%20of%20drowning&f=false)

So, it could be argued that (since we have no way of knowing) some of the drowning victims portrayed in shows like Baywatch are in the very earliest stages of drowning and have only gone unconscious rather than gone into cardiac arrest, which would make their resuscitation plausible.

However, it does seem awfully convenient that they often revive their victims consistently in the most dramatic (yet, consistently vomit-free) way possible. Again, as it would seem is often the case with television and film, those telling the story tend to cherry-pick the most convenient and plot-friendly aspects of CPR.

Comment: +1, I'd also add: the most unrealistic parts of CPR on TV are: compressions alone saving the patient, and defibrillation of asystole. CPR without Defibrillation is like jumping out of a plane without a parachute: not many are going to make it.

Comment: I was once a witness of such a CPR. The guy was almost 20 minutes under water, because it took that long until the divers arrived. Then it took another 15 minutes until they found him. Bringing him back to live took at least another 15 minutes or more. TBH I didn't believe that they would get him back. Well, the guy lived, but it was certainly not like in the movies, where they just suddenly take a deep breath and are done with. He was just flat on his back and got pushed in the emergency car.